# Can a MongoDB query with $or be a covered query?

Tags: mongodb

I want to use an index for my query without retrieving documents ("covered query"), and my query has an $or. Is this possible?

There isn't anything in the documentation I've read to make me think this is impossible, yet my empirical testing suggests otherwise:

```
> db.inventory.createIndex( { quantity: 1 } )
> db.inventory.createIndex( { price: 1 } )
> db.inventory.insert({quantity:5, price: 10})
> db.inventory.insert({quantity:4, price: 20})
> db.inventory.insert({quantity:50, price: 5})

> db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 5 } ] }, {_id:0,quantity:1} ).explain({verbose: "executionSummary"})["executionStats"]["totalDocsExamined"]
3
```

The full execution stats shows something like: `PROJECTION < FETCH < OR < [IXSCAN (quantity_1), IXSCAN (price_1)]`

A covered query would have 0 documents examined.

Are $or queries are really not supported as covered queries? If they aren't, can I restructure my query in a way that would be supported? Or do I need to submit a separate query for each of the $or clauses?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a simpler query:

```
db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: 20 }, { price: 5 } ] }, {_id:0,price:1} ).explain({verbose: "executionSummary"})
```

This query is supposed to return the price for all of the documents where quantity is 20. But, you are also asking it to use the quantity index to match the documents where quantity is 20. How is it supposed to obtain the price for the documents where quantity is 20, only using the quantity index?

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense for my example. I'm still looking for an answer to the broader question though. Can a compound index be used in these cases?

Comment: Try it and see what happens?